# Java app doesn't recognize OpenJDK (from AdoptOpenJDK)

Tags: java, macos

I've removed Oracle's Java from my Mac (running 10.14 Mojave), and then installed OpenJDK from AdoptOpenJDK.

I can run Eclipse using the OpenJDK, and the terminal tells me

```
 $ java -version
 openjdk version "1.8.0_282"
 OpenJDK Runtime Environment (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 1.8.0_282-b08)
 OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 25.282-b08, mixed mode)
```

However, I have a Java app that now tells me "Unable to load Java runtime environment" upon start.

It looks like the app does not find the Java runtime, but I have no idea why that is so and how I could fix it?

Comment: What do you mean by Java app - dewtails of it please and how do you run it

Comment: @mmmmmm Not sure what you're asking for. It's a Mac App, so if I inspect the app package, I see the typical macOS structure with Contents folder etc. and Info.plist file containing `<key>JVMMainClassName</key><string>de.eq3.max.MaxLocalAppStarter.Application</string>`
 (and more, of course). I don't know exactly what macOS looks for to determine how to start such a Java app. If you could guide me to the right location, that would be awesome!

Comment: What is in xx.app/Contents/MacOS

Comment: @mmmmmm A file called JavaAppLauncher

Comment: I think that is an Oracle one - and perhaps now unsupported. I would put the Oracle jre back. The correct thing to do now is for developers to embed the jre in their app

Comment: @mmmmmm So what you're saying is that it's impossible to run a Java app with OpenJDK that hasn't been designed to run with OpenJDK? But this would mean that using OpenJDK instead of Oracle breaks almost all existing Java apps?

Comment: No this just your current app

Comment: @mmmmmm But then there must be something different in this app that could hopefully be fixed. Perhaps by replacing Contents/MacOS/JavaAppLauncher?